# Quando o teclado é escondido o espaço não é renderizado

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Estou com um problema em uma das Activitys, nessa Activity tenho muito conteúdo, então estou utilizando um ScrollView. O problema é que assim que termino de digitar no EditText e o teclado é escondido o espaço que o teclado estava ocupando fica branco, ele não volta a exibir o conteúdo da Activity. Isso acontece apenas na primeira vez que digito no primeiro EditText da tela. Estou testando o aplicativo no Android 4.2.
Testei o aplicativo em um celular com Android 7.0 e o erro não ocorreu.

Abaixo o print da tela:

[image: Print do erro]

O XML do EditText é esse:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/cad_perguntas_edt_enunciado"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
  android:ems="10"
  android:hint="@string/cad_perg_enun_hint"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
  android:theme="@style/EditTextPadrao"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"            
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/cad_perguntas_txt_enunciado"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/cad_perguntas_txt_enunciado" 
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cad_perguntas_txt_enunciado" />
```

Alguém tem ideia do que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca o ScrowView dentro de um relative layout, no SV coloca:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: De nada! Boa sorte!